# Is integral of a smooth function smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ such that $f,\,\nabla f\in L^1(\mathbb R^2)\,$.
Consider the function
$$ F(y)\,:=\, \int_\mathbb R f(x,y)\; dx \;.$$
Can I say that $F\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ ?

By Leibnitz integral rule, I know that there exists
$$ F'(y) \,=\, \int_\mathbb R \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)\; dx $$
since $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\cdot,y)\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ . Can I go further and conclude for higher derivatives? Are additional hypothesis needed?

Comment: How do you even know that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\cdot,y)\in L^1(\mathbb R)$??? (Yes, for higher derivatives you need higher-order hypotheses. But we should get $D_x$ straight first...) **In fact** I see no reason to think that the integral defining $F$ converges...

Comment: @David If I understand correctly, the point that you are making is that something like $$f(\mathbf x)\overset{\text{Def.}}=\mathbf 1_{\lvert\mathbf x\rvert\le 1}\frac1{\lvert\mathbf x\rvert}$$ is in $L^1(\mathbb R^2)$, $\mathbf x=(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2$, but $x\mapsto f(x, 0)\not\in L^1(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich you are right, I only now it for almost every $y$